# how to create an array and reuse in scala template play framework 2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to create an array in one of my index.scala.html. Later I want to use that array to store some values.

I want to achieve following index.scala.html

```
@import scala._

@myArray = @{ArrayList()};
```

and I am getting an error saying

> not found value @myArray

If above problem is resolved I want to reuser @myArray to add String values. How I can do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can declare and use a new variable like this:

```
@import java.util._

@defining(new ArrayList[String]()) { myArray =>
    @{
      myArray.add("1")
      myArray.add("2")
      myArray.add("3")
      ""
    }

    @for(s <- myArray) {
        @s
    }
}
```

But I definitely don't recommend it because it makes your template code a mess. Do it in a controller.

Comment: 100% agree about controller, also you can add a method in your model like in `computer-database` Java sample